# is there any way to load local data set folder directly from google drive to google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

[see the image carefully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA5M9.png)i couldn't load custom data folder from google drive to google colab.though i mounted google drive.like instead of MNIST data set i want to load my own image data set folder.i have tried pydrive wrapper.but i need simple solution.
suppose i have dataset of images inside google drive.how to load it to google colab?

```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then

```
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('Hello Google Drive!')
   !cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/foo.txt
```

here insted of foo.txt i have an image folder called Dog inside ml-data folder.but i can't load it.how to load it in google colab directly from google drive as it is in my local hard drive.

Comment: Is there any logs that you can share?

Comment: i uploaded an image.please check.and read the description.

Answer (score 1):

To load data directly from the local machine, you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to files [left side menu]

[image: See this]

2. Click on upload to session storage

[image: Click on upload to session storage]

3. Select file(s) from your machine to upload

[image]

4. It will prompt something indicating that file(s) will be available for the current session only, click ok.
5. The file(s) will be uploaded in the directory. Click on it (left and right-click both work the same).

[image]

And then;

[image]

6. Copy path & use it inside pd.read_csv() function.

[image]

**Note:** After the session is terminated, files will be lost from colab session. To use it again, you'll need to upload it again.
Many times, we prefer to it have all our data in a GitHub repository or in a google drive folder to fetch from there.

Answer (score 0):

Reading many files from Google Drive through colab is going to be less performant and more unreliable than first copying a .zip or similar single file from Drive to the colab VM and unzipping it outside the drive mount directory, and then using that copy of the data.