# How do I upload a local csv for use in Google Colab with an R kernel?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

The only results for this question that I see is to use Python to either mount the drive or load through git/gist, etc.

This is how I'm currently loading the R kernel ([How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory)): load the Demo.ipynb and it somehow retains the R kernel for me when I save a copy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try/investigate? Have also a look at the [ask] link.

Comment: Here's the complete answer with screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101903/5114585

Answer (score 3):

I'm dumb and figured out a workaround

In case anyone else has this problem:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0q7z.png)

Click on the arrow to expand the window, Files -> Upload

It should give you a warning that the files will get deleted after the runtime is refreshed.