# How do I import a csv file into Google Colab that uses R kernel?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I have a csv on my computer that I can upload to Google Drive. I am trying to use a Google colab but in R and not Python. How can I import this csv?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use R with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595285/how-to-use-r-with-google-colaboratory)

Comment: Not really, but the python and R trick worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57927212/5333248

Here a workaround for you.

Lateral arrow on top-left of the screen >> files >> upload.

In this way you can upload the .csv file from your pc. 
There's even a Mount Drive option in the same path, but as I understand is only for python.

The file last only for the current session. You'll need to re-upload it every time you reopen the notebook on Google Colab!

[Just to clarify which is the lateral arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXvqs.png)