# using a drive address from computer into google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to python and google colab. I want to run this part of code in google colab. but i get the error: no such file or directory...this code is run on my computer and I get the image, well.
can you help me?

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

BASEDIR = "e:\datasets\Caltech60\train\001.ak47"

list_open =mpimg.imread(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '001_0001.jpg'))
plt.imshow(list_open)
```

Comment: Technically, the colab notebooks run on Google's server and does not have access to your local file system. Best way is to upload your data to google drive and load from there.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I import a csv file into Google Colab that uses R kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951094/how-do-i-import-a-csv-file-into-google-colab-that-uses-r-kernel/59060973#59060973)

Here I pointed how to upload your data to google colab, you must then change in your code
`BASEDIR="001.ak47"`

Let me know if it works, as wrote in the answer there is a mount drive option for python kernel in case you want to use it (as you mention drive address in your question)

Comment: "001.ak47" is a folder and I can't upload it to colab...should I zip it?

Comment: now I get it. Yes, zip it and unzip in colab with  !unzip name.zip

Comment: how should I unzip zip and tar files in colab?

Comment: tar.7z file? or other extension? for zip I edited the comment

Comment: you can try this, but I've not experience with tar, usually use rar or zip.  !apt-get install tar      !tar xvf file.tar    . Let me know if it worked

Comment: !tar xvf file.tar works, but in middle I get the error :tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Try !tar xf file.tar . There are plenty of Q/A about this problem in stackoverflow [other suggestions are illegal characters in filenames,  archive has been renamed before unzip,  different tar version between zip/unzip phase, etc]. You should search a solution between them and consider closed this question. The problem I don't believe resides on Colab specifically.